# How to reparse xml data in tableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, xml-parsing, tableview

I have a tableView where the user can add contacts to. These contacts get saved to a mysql database and then returned to the user. Thing is, he has to update it manually in order to get the updated xml. But I wanna do it when he adds a contact so it gets shown right away. I tried various things and always ended up with either an error or he parsed the database more than once in the tableview. I thought of deleting all contacts and pasting all of them again and then update it, but this also didn't really work. 
Here is how I do it at the moment:

```
To parse the XML:

- (void) doXMLParsing 
{
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key22"] == nil) {

} else {
self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.tabelle count]];

self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

tabelle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"Key22"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.---.com/%@.xml", fileName];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

DataFileToObjectParser *myParser = [[DataFileToObjectParser alloc] parseXMLAtUrl:url toObject:@"Telefonbuch" parseError:nil];

for(int i = 0; i < [[myParser items] count]; i++) {
    Telefonbuch *new = [[Telefonbuch alloc] init];
    new = (Telefonbuch *) [[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i];
    [tabelle addObject:new];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
[XMLActivity stopAnimating];
}
}
```

In the viewDidLoad:

```
XMLActivity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 290.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
[XMLActivity setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

[self.view addSubview:XMLActivity];

[XMLActivity startAnimating];

[self performSelector:@selector(doXMLParsing)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:0];
return;
tabelle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Everything works fine right now. I just want to reparse the XML after a new contact is added so it will get displayed right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was as obvious as simple, and I still wasted way too many time on this. 
Here is the solution:

Just put

```
[self doXMLParsing];
```

at the end when you added a contact to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `[reloadData][1]` on your UITableView?

If this does not answer, could you explain what happens exactly when you parse xml a second time?

Comment: Hey, I do it with [tableview reloadData], but I'll try it with your code. When i parse it a second time I have the old database and the new one (with the added contact) in a tableview. So a duplicate with one new contact.